# Azure Service Bus hostname conflicts resolution

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

Azure Service Bus Instance has name parameter (For example,`sample-name`).
This name used to expose endpoint URL to host

`sample-name.servicebus.windows.net`

Whats happens if another client choose the same `sample-name` for another instance of Azure Service Bus?

How it is resolved by Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This name is universal in Azure. If you've created a Namespace with some name, then no other user can create a Namespace with that same name.

Essentially the URL for your Azure Service Bus has to be unique in Azure ecosystem i.e. no two users can have a URL `<somename>.servicebus.windows.net`.

What this means is that if you have a general Azure Subscription and an Azure Subscription in Germany (or China/US Gov), you could create a namespace with same name in there (one in general region and other in Germany/China/US Gov) as the endpoint domain (e.g. servicebus.windows.net) is different in each of these regions.

Answer (score 2):

Azure checks availability of the namespace. If it's taken, the portal will say so:

[image: Taken namespace message on Azure portal]